# Docusign - Editing fields and downloading without sending it

Tags: field, restful-authentication, docusignapi

I have a question relative to Docusign  , I have send the document to be signed, after completion I just want some fields from the complete pdf in my local ,  Is it possible to populate the fields and download this envelope without send it  using REST API  or Edit the complete PDF ?

Comment: I'm confused on what you're asking, first you say you want the fields from a completed envelope, but then you are asking if you can download the fields without sending the envelope.  Which one are you trying to do?  You trying to get the field data without sending the envelope?

Comment: You can download the completed PDF, you can populate fields and get their values through API.  You should probably not look to alter the completed PDFs because that's your evidence of signing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DocuSign, when an envelope is signed and completed any form fields that were layered on the document become part of the document.  They are "burned" into the document content and part of it moving forward.  If you download a completed envelope, you'll see the values of the form fields in your document(s).

On the other hand, if you are trying to download a pending or "In-Process" envelope, or even a draft envelope that has not been sent to anyone yet, the values of the form fields are not part of the document content yet since no recipients have signed off on them yet.  However, at this point it is still possible to download the values of your form fields.

---

To download the form field values of an In-Process or Draft envelope, you can make the following call, with the `include_tabs=true` query parameter appended to the URL:

**Get Envelope Recipient Status**

```
This returns the status for all recipients of a single envelope and identifies the current routing order. The current routing order is a number that matches up to the routingOrder for envelope recipients, which shows that the envelope has been sent to a recipient, but the recipient has not completed their actions.
```

**URL**:

```
/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients
```

Optional query items: include_tabs={true or false}, include_extended={true or false}

**Formats**:

```
XML, JSON
```

**HTTP Method**:

```
GET
```

**Parameters**:

The only required parameter is the envelope ID. If the optional query include_tabs is set to true, the 
tabs associated with the recipient are returned. If the optional query include_extended is set to true, 
the extended properties are returned.

---

And to download a completed document, please see API Walkthrough #6, called `Get Document List & Download Docs`:

http://iodocs.docusign.com/apiwalkthroughs

This is the call that the walkthrough makes:

---

**Get Envelope Documents and Certificate**

This retrieves a PDF containing the combined content of all documents and the certificate. If the account has the Highlight Data Changes feature enabled, there is an option to request that any changes in the envelope be highlighted.

**URL**:

/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/combined

Optional additions: certificate={true or false}, show_changes={true}, watermark={true or false}

**Formats**:

XML, JSON

**HTTP Method**:

GET